# Sometimes running xcode test on CLI returns "manager not ready"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, continuous-integration

I normally run my xcode unit tests on command line using these commands:

clean:

```
xcodebuild -workspace appName.xcworkspace -scheme "Shared appName" -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 5s,OS=8.1" clean
```

then build:

```
xcodebuild -workspace appName.xcworkspace -scheme "Shared appName" -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 5s,OS=8.1" build
```

then test (with dry run):

```
xcodebuild -workspace appName.xcworkspace -scheme "Shared appName" -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 5s,OS=8.1" test -dry-run
```

and I sometimes I get this error:

```
2015-02-27 11:01:50.417 Registering for testmanagerd availability notify post.
2015-02-27 11:01:50.417 testmanagerd availability notify_get_state check indicated manager not ready, waiting for notify post.
2015-02-27 11:02:50.371 60s elapsed since launch without testing starting, sending logs to stderr
```

any idea how to prevent this from happening? I'm assuming that the testmanagerd is a test daemon or something? Where can I find documentation about that?

Comment: Happens to us for one machine... Only after deleting DerivedData though, so on first compile/test.  Very annoying. Did you figure it out?

Answer (score -3):

This timeout usually means that your mac is too slow and it took more than expected to run the simulator. You should start thinking in getting a new machine.

Comment: I don't think its a coincidence that you just have (at the time you wrote this answer) one point on SO